# Using value(forKey: String) gives an error

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to retrieve data from Firebase but I've run into a problem and I can't seem to solve it. Here is my code:

```
Database.database().reference().child("Users").child(userID!).observeSingleEvent(of: .value) { (snapshot) in

        if let name = snapshot.value(forKey: "name") as? String {
            userName = name
            print(userName)
        }

        if let username = snapshot.value(forKey: "Username") as? String {
            userUsername = username
            print(userUsername)
        }

        if let email = snapshot.value(forKey: "Email") as? String {
            userEmail = email
            print(userEmail)
        }

}
```

Running this gives me an error:

> 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '[
>   valueForUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant
>   for the key Username.'

Here is a picture of my database:

[image]

Comment: Regarding the *name* key: Please ***read*** the picture. Hint: case sensitivity matters.

Comment: Oh my bad, still get the same error tho

Comment: can you print snapshot?

Comment: @SMALLworld I know. `snapshot` is a dictionary. See Sh_Khan's answer.

Comment: exception says it's not a dictionary, show snapshot object

Comment: @vadian oh yeah that's the correct answer, I just can't accept it yet, Stack overflow is asking me to wait for a few minutes

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to cast `snapshot.value` which of type `Any` to `[String:String]`

```
Database.database().reference().child("Users").child(userID!).observeSingleEvent(of: .value) { (snapshot) in

   guard let res = snapshot.value as? [String:String] else { return }

    if let name = res["name"] {
        userName = name
        print(userName)
    }

    if let username = res["Username"]  {
        userUsername = username
        print(userUsername)
    }

    if let email = res["Email"] {
        userEmail = email
        print(userEmail)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

First Convert snapshot value to Dictionary and then get value from it like below

```
Database.database().reference().child("Users").child(userID!).observeSingleEvent(of: .value) { (snapshot) in

          if let data = snapshot.value as? [String: String] {
            let name = data["name"]!
            let email = data["email"]!
            let userName = data["Username"]!
          }
```